# Please burninate the [loading] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[loading](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/loading) doesn't sound like a very useful tag to me.

16 questions are tagged with it and I request that it is burninated!

Comment: `LOAD "*",8,1`... just sayin :)  But seriously, [loading] is like "thinking"

Comment: There are multiple definitions for this.  It provides no useful categorization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: It always makes me happy to see a good "burninated!" post from Jeff!